# Recyclerview does not response to touch and also does not scroll after loading the data for first time

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

following lines of code is a part of my fragment. I am searching a data inside onStart() method of my fragment and I am getting result back in showResult() method. but **whenever I search data for the time my recyclerView displays the result but does not response to touch and does not scroll up/down, but when I search for a data second time, recyclerView starts working fine.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    App.getInstance().getAppComponent().inject(this);

    forwardInteraction = new StashPresenter(this, getContext(),
            gettyImageFactory);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

   /*Following 4 lines of code adds Artist-Name Suggestion(AutoComplete) Feature to SearchView from artistNamesSuggestion array*/
    String[] artistNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.artistNamesSuggestion);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterArtist = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.auto_complete, artistNames);
    searchView.setAdapter(adapterArtist);
    searchView.setThreshold(1);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(space, space, space, space));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
}


@Override
public void showResult(List<BaseViewModel> viewModels) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    adapter.setViewModels(viewModels);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
}

@Override
public void showToastMessage(String message) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    searchView.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            forwardInteraction.searchButtonClick(actionId, searchView.getText().toString());
            searchView.setText("");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    App.getInstance().getAppComponent().inject(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, MainFragment.newInstance(), "mainFragment")
            .commitNow();
}
}
```

ViewModelAdapter Class

```
public class ViewModelAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private final List<BaseViewModel> viewModels;
private final SparseArrayCompat<BaseViewModel> viewTypeMap;


@Inject
public ViewModelAdapter() {
    viewModels = new ArrayList<>();
    viewTypeMap = new SparseArrayCompat<>();
}


public void setViewModels(Collection<? extends BaseViewModel> viewModels) {
    this.viewModels.clear();
    viewTypeMap.clear();
    addAll(viewModels);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return viewTypeMap.get(viewType).createViewHolder(parent);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    viewModels.get(position).bindViewHolder(holder);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return viewModels.size();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return viewModels.get(position).getViewType().getId();
}


private void addAll(Collection<? extends BaseViewModel> viewModels) {
    if (viewModels == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (BaseViewModel baseViewModel : viewModels) {
        this.viewModels.add(baseViewModel);

        //If there are multiple items of the same type the index will just update
        viewTypeMap.put(baseViewModel.getViewType().getId(), baseViewModel);
    }
}
}
```

SpaceItemDecoration Class

```
public class SpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private final int left;
private final int right;
private final int top;
private final int bottom;

public SpaceItemDecoration(int left, int right, int top, int bottom) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.top = top;
    this.bottom = bottom;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.left = left;
    outRect.right = right;
    outRect.top = top;
    outRect.bottom = bottom;
}
}
```

**main_activity Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.stashinvest.stashchallenge.view.ui.activity.MainActivity">

<fragment 
class="com.stashinvest.stashchallenge.view.ui.fragment.MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: There's probably something which blocks your UI. You can verify if this is the case by enabling the `Show surface updates` toggle in the Developer options of the device. If the screen is blinking during your first search, check your lifecycle methods to see what is causing the constant UI updates

Comment: There is something that for first time block UI (maybe a load?)

Comment: @Sammekl I have noticed that onResume() method of fragment is getting called for two time.

Comment: @Sammekl my screen gonna update constantly because my cursor is blinking inside edit text, problem I am facing is I can see my onResume method is getting called for two time in a row but I don't know why.

Comment: @Saret I was doubting on progressBar, I am setting visibility of it to Gone anyway.

Comment: @KAUSTUBH MEMANE If you place a breakpoint there you can see what invokes the onResume in the stack. It might have something to do with the way you manage your fragments

Comment: @KAUSTUBHMEMANE I don't think that change of visibily can block the UI. The code is not completed and is difficult to understand what the code do but basically if you want to show and hide a progress bar I expect to see something like a AsyncTask somewhere (something async that do the work and not block the UI thread)

Comment: @Saret Yes I am accessing images from remote server using RxAndroid and Retrofit.. After receiving a data in onNext() method of Observer, I am just hiding the progressBar and displaying data in recyclerView.

Comment: @Sammekl I am seeing endless loop of behind the scene function call.

Comment: @Sammekl I have updated a question you can see my mainActity code

Comment: You need to post your adapter + item decoration class

Comment: @Ricardo Posted!

Comment: what does this do exactly? forwardInteraction.searchButtonClick(actionId, searchView.getText().toString());

Comment: @ricardo it just searching data over remote server.. using mvp that&#39;s why I have moved all the functionality/operation to presenter. Thats Nothing to do with my view.

Comment: @Ricardo what do you think, Found anything wrong in it?

Comment: What is `fragment_container` in the `activity_main` layout? That is, what kind of `<>` tag is it?

Comment: @MikeM. I have updated it in my question!

Comment: The `<fragment>` tag in the layout actually creates a `Fragment` instance when that layout is inflated. It's not just a placeholder. You're ending up with two `MainFragment`s, one sitting on top of the other. You can just remove the `FragmentTransaction` you have in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`. Alternatively, if you need to be able to transact that `Fragment` dynamically in your code, change the `<fragment>` to a `<FrameLayout>`, and remove the `class` attribute.

Comment: @MikeM. Problem SOLVED!